# WYSIWYG+code webpage editor for Mac or online, generates clean HTML (bootstrap, foundation?)

Tags: web-development, css, html-editor, wysiwyg, bootstrap

I'm looking for a webpage editor that satisfies these criteria:

- It is useable both by me (I could write the HTML and CSS by hand) and my wife who is not a computer person at all. I would set up the webpage and design, but she should be able to add and exchange pictures, add and edit text, and such basic activities.

  - WYSIWGY is a must
  - Good usability required
  - Must be a visual editor, my wife doesn't know HTML
  - Ok if not everything can be edited in the editor (e.g. javascript for menues and picture zoom is added by hand)
- I runs either native on Mac or is an Online tool
- Builds clean HTML, Bootstrap preferred (because I know it), Foundation or any other framework would be ok as well.
- Good styling support. I'd like to define a theme that will be used on all pages and components so my wife doesn't have to worry about CSS and colours and fonts.
- Can be a paid app as long as there's a demo or trial so I can check it before buying.

I have done some research on tools available, but so far I've found that they are either too technical (i.e. you need to understand HTML to use them, which my wife doesn't) or too simplistic, e.g. only allow you to change built-in layouts and themes (which is not enough for what I want to do).

Answer (score 1):

you could check out [pinegrow](https://pinegrow.com)

I use and own this software like me your wife will be able to learn about css and html  because you can see the the code affects the elements

it meets  your requirements

namely WYSIWGY ,

bootstrap

easy to use,

runs  on Mac
 and
 they have a trial

being actively developed

and usually have a few discounts every year can either buy outright or subscription